# Cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working at a predicition model for sports and I encountered this problem.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-90981affcf54> in <module>
     18     #print("Home",home_rank)
     19     #print("Visitor",visitor_rank)
---> 20     row["HomeTeamRanksHigher"] = int(home_rank) > int(visitor_rank)
     21     a = int(int(home_rank) < int(visitor_rank))
     22     dataset.at[index,"HomeTeamRanksHigher"] = a

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    127         if len(self) == 1:
    128             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 129         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    130 
    131     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Here is my code.

```
dataset["HomeTeamRanksHigher"]= 0
for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    home_team = row["Home"]
    visitor_team = row["Away"]
    home_rank = standings[standings["Squad"] == home_team]["Rk"]
    visitor_rank = standings[standings["Squad"] == visitor_team]["Rk"]
    #print("Home",home_rank)
    #print("Visitor",visitor_rank)
    row["HomeTeamRanksHigher"] = int(home_rank) > int(visitor_rank)
    a = int(int(home_rank) < int(visitor_rank))
    dataset.at[index,"HomeTeamRanksHigher"] = a
```

I checked the dtype of "HomeTeamRanksHigher" after I casted it to int and it is int64. I used pd.to_numeric and .astype(int) too.

```
standings["Rk"] = pd.to_numeric(standings["Rk"])
dataset["HomeTeamRanksHigher"] = pd.to_numeric(dataset["HomeTeamRanksHigher"])
```

Here are my columns data types

```
Country                        object
League                         object
Season                         object
Date                   datetime64[ns]
Time                           object
Home                           object
Away                           object
HG                              int64
AG                              int64
HomeWin                          bool
HomeLastWin                     int64
VisitorLastWin                  int64
HomeTeamRanksHigher             int64
dtype: object
```

In Standings most of the columns are int64. I cannot post any more code

Answer (score 1):

Most likely these two selections are returning multiple results for certain teams:

```py
home_rank = standings[standings["Squad"] == home_team]["Rk"]
visitor_rank = standings[standings["Squad"] == visitor_team]["Rk"]
```

`int(home_rank)` will work if `home_rank` is just 1 result, but if `home_rank` is a multi-value series, it will throw that TypeError.

You can verify by checking:

```py
standings.groupby("Squad").Rk.value_counts().max()
```

If this output is not 1, then you have some duplicate `Squad` / `Rk` pairs.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment :) The output is 1. In  "dataset" I have the history of matches and in "standings" my teams are unique. The error that I get if I remove the int from home_rank and visitor_rank is: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`